# Why is OR not working as expected inside the IF statement?

Tags: node.js, lambda

I have a function to upload a file to S3 and want to only allow PNG and (JPG, JPEG) images to be uploaded.  I added the following check;

```
 if(fileExtension.toUpperCase() != 'png'.toUpperCase() || fileExtension.toUpperCase() != 
 'jpeg'.toUpperCase() || fileExtension.toUpperCase() != 'jpg'.toUpperCase()) {
 return {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify("Not a valid capture format.  Capture upload only accepts PNG and 
  (JPG,JPEG)"),
     };
 }
 else {
  // Upload capture
}
```

What happens is that it returns the error message below to say it is not a valid capture format even when I expect it to be.  For example, `filePrefix` is `jpg` therefore I expect it to go into the `else` statement.

**EDIT**

How can I only allow files with the PNG, JPG or JPEG extensions to be uploaded to S3? If it is anything other than those extensions, I want to return an error as shown above.

Thanks all.

Comment: If `filePrefix` is `"blah"` then it's NOT any of the cases and thus the statement is true. If it's `"png"` then it's NOT `"jpeg"` so the condition is still true. If it's `"jpeg"`, then it's NOT `"png"` - again true. There is no way for this condition to ever be false.

Comment: jpg is != png ... so why should it execute the else statement

Comment: I missed my coffee this morning...Thanks guys! Makes perfect sense.

Comment: `filePrefix` is also a little confusing as a prefix generally comes _before_ anything else, perhaps you should rename that variable `fileExtension`

Comment: @phuzi, Yes, agreed.  That being said, I was just thinking how the above can be achieved in a nice way.  Any suggestions? I'll edit my question above.

Comment: Change the `||`s to `&&`s ==> If it's not a "png" __and__ it's not "jpg" __and__ it's not "jpeg" then return an error

Comment: Or you could swap the logic ==> If it is a "png" __or__ it is "jpg" __or__ it is "jpeg" then process upload, otherwise return the error

Comment: Yup, ideal! Thanks for that.  You can answer below if you want and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your logic is a little off!

As it stands, you're checking whether the file extension is *not* "png" or not "jpg" or not "jpeg". As it can never be all 3 and the test must return true every time.

You should do one of two things.

1. Change the `||`s to `&&`s so that: If it's not a "png" and it's not "jpg" and it's not "jpeg" then return an error

```
    if(fileExtension.toUpperCase() != 'png'.toUpperCase() && fileExtension.toUpperCase() != 
     'jpeg'.toUpperCase() && fileExtension.toUpperCase() != 'jpg'.toUpperCase()) {
        // return error
    } else {
        // process upload
    }
```

or,

2. Invert the logic and change the `!=` to `==`

```
    if(fileExtension.toUpperCase() == 'png'.toUpperCase() || fileExtension.toUpperCase() == 'jpeg'.toUpperCase() || fileExtension.toUpperCase() == 'jpg'.toUpperCase()) {
        // process upload
    } else {
        // return error
    }
```